# Find conditions for there to exist a morphism of rings from $\mathbb{Z}_m$ to $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know that a necessary and sufficient condition for a ring morphism $\mathbb Z_m\to\mathbb Z_n$ to exist is that $n$ must divide $m$. However, I am having trouble understanding a proof that this condition is necessary.

My professor says that the multiplicative identity $1\in\mathbb{Z}_m$ has order $m$ and $1'\in\mathbb{Z}_n$ has order $n$. Now, if $f:\mathbb{Z}_m\to\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a morphism of rings then $f(1) = 1'$ by definition. Then, $f(m) = f(m1) = mf(1)=m1' = 0\in\mathbb{Z}_n$. Therefore, $n$ divides $m$.

I don't understand how this equation implies that $n$ divides $m$.

Comment: I think it should be $f(m1) = mf(1) = m1'$.

Comment: I thought that calculation seemed off, but that's exactly how my prof wrote it on my paper.

Comment: @WillMaxwell If I went too far with my edit, feel free to rollback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are groups with respect to addition. Let's use a multiplicative group $G$ first. If you know that an element $g\in G$ has order $n$ (that is, $n$ is the minimum positive integer such that $g^n=1$), then from $g^m=1$ you can deduce that $n$ divides $m$.

In additive notation it's just the same: if an element $g$ of $G$ has order $n$ (that is, $n$ is the minimum positive integer such that $ng=0$), then from $mg=0$ you can deduce that $n$ divides $m$.

The order of the identity element in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is exactly $n$.

---

If you want to see it with cosets, then saying that $m(1+n\mathbb{Z})=0+n\mathbb{Z}$ means that $m\in n\mathbb{Z}$, that is, $n$ divides $m$.